# param is missing or empty - jsonapi rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The request payload is as follows.

```
{"vertical":{"certification_ids":[7,1]}}
```

permit data is as follows

```
def create_params
  params.require(:vertical).permit(certification_ids: [])
end
```

But i am getting the following response

```
{"errors":"param is missing or the value is empty: vertical"}
```

params that is seen in the rails console is as follows

```
"params":{"_jsonapi":{"vertical":{"certification_ids":[7]}},"vertical_id":"1"},
```

So i assume the issue is due to the "_jsonapi" key that is somehow shown in the params.

Any idea on how to fix this issue?

Note: I was using jsonapi gem in my project. But i dont want to use it anymore on new apis.

Comment: Yes, your params should be `"params":{"vertical":{"certification_ids":[7]},"vertical_id":"1"},`

Comment: but somehow the params is inside "_jsonapi". I am not sure how to remove this..

Comment: @prajeesh Can you post your `render` code from `create` action?